# Get produсt by category ids passed as query parameter

Tags: url, category-products

I want to use the URL http://mydomain.test/category-name.html?cat=9,10,40
I need to get all products from category "category-name" and categories with ids 9, 10 and 40.

How can I do this. Maybe there is such an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the products for category 9 you can do this:

```
$category_id = 9;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

You can do this for the other categories.

to print the products you can do something like this:

```
foreach ($products as $_product) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
    </a>
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
        <?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

If you want a list try something like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
        array('finset' => '9'),
        array('finset' => '10'),
        array('finset' => '40')
    )
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
```

Comment: Thanks
But I know this.
I need get producs-list by cat=9,10,20, and show on catalog list page

Comment: I've added something more, hope this works for you